# Apache Configuration - Directory

Tags: apache

I am trying to figure out why i can not access my folder for web-mail yet i have got the correct location and copied a working directory above.

`Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /mail on this server.`

and HTTPD.exe reports

`[Thu Dec 11 11:08:32.771044 2014] [core:warn] [pid 2340:tid 192] AH00114: Useless use of AllowOverride in line 674 of C:/Program Files/Apache/conf/httpd.conf.`

yet WPad works correctly with the exact same settings.

I am thoroughly confused with theses results.

```
<Directory "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data/wpad">
    #This one Works
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all

    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

<Location "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data/WebMail">
   #This one dose not work
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   #line 674 is below this
    AllowOverride all

    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</location>

<Directory "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "all",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options all"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "all", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Alias /mail "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data/WebMail"
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using <Location instead of <Directory?

Comment: No there is no reason. That's a missuses of <location is it not, i feel dumb for even asking now i recently changed from IIS to Apache and well learning curve.

Comment: Hay man! Don't be hard on yourself. We all started somewhere. I actually started way back with O'Reilly and Apache, then on to IIS, then back to Apache. I cannot tell you anything about IIS anymore. Two of my development servers are IIS. How crazy is that?!

Comment: The reason why i was using IIS was for my Powershell scripts that change AD passwords. I posted that to code review. After some research i changed to Apache and now Apache runs the scripts faster and closes them in a timely fashion. Also do you want to post your comment as the answer.

Comment: I used to be a web host mostly with Linux, Apache, Postfix, Postgress, and so on, but I did use Windows for my robot server and Exchange server as the SMTP gateway for all of the servers. As well, I was a consultant supporting nearly 1000 Windows IIS, Exchange, Proxy Server, and SQLServer. I was also a Windows programmer both VB and VBScript then .Net. I preferred Apache big time, but still liked Windows enough to be happy. BTW- I did post an/the answer after finding some documentation to support what I was thinking. I had to refresh my memory. Getting old.

Comment: I have only just started. 3 Years in the field and been through so much already dealing with servers and being help desk. Unfortunately i have no one to talk to since i am the only IT guy in this company.

Comment: Well, we are here for you when you need us. I am retired from IT but still do automated security analysis research to support other researchers who are more theoretical. Outside of that, there is the farm land, the part-time antiques business, I am a landlord, and I try and do physical work like heavy construction and property renovation as much as I can. I like physical work! I got tired of sitting behind a desk and moved to the mountains. My old friends would hardly recognize me. I look like a regular hillbilly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19373/discussion-between-werezwolf-and-closetnoc).

Comment: I am there and have responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your   to

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

```
Only available in <Directory> sections

AllowOverride is valid only in <Directory> sections specified without regular
expressions, not in <Location>, <DirectoryMatch> or <Files> sections.
```